# Loading Images from an array to the screen on iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, arrays, debugging

Im new to Xcode and im trying to pull a bunch of pictures from an array and put them on the screen but through the debugger i see that my for loop is not running.

```
for (int i = 0; i <[imagePaths count]; i++)
{
    NSLog(@"I'm loading a card");

    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 250, 350)];
    NSString *imgFilepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[imagePaths objectAtIndex:i] ofType:@"jpg"];
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imgFilepath];
    [imgView setImage:img];
    [self.view addSubview:imgView];

}
```

Does anyone see what im missing to make this work?

Comment: is `imagePaths` equal to `nil`?

Comment: Images are of sure .jpg not .png/.jpeg format? IMO that can also cause problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i see that my for loop is not running.

Check your `[imagePaths count]` using below code before the loop .

It will be zero. That means your `imagePaths` array will be `null`

```
NSlog(@"imagePaths count is: %d",[imagePaths count]);
```

Comment: I tried adding that line of code above the for loop but it gives me 2 errors. Apple Mach-o Linker Error "_NSlog", referenced from: -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController.o         and    Apple Mach-O Linker Error, Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)   any ideas?

Comment: yes. use NSLog(@"imagePaths count is: %d",[imagePaths count]);

Comment: The code worked without errors now but the count is 0

Comment: yup.. that the reason,,,,

Answer (score 0):

```
// Check what your imagePaths array contains, if it contains full path of image including filename and extension then use following code
for (int i = 0; i <[imagePaths count]; i++)
{
    NSLog(@"I'm loading a card");

    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 250, 350)];
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[imagePaths objectAtIndex:i]];
    [imgView setImage:img];
    [self.view addSubview:imgView];
}
```

Comment: Can you explain for a complete noob? haha

Answer (score 0):

If it's not running then imagePaths must be nil. Add a breakpoint right before it and check to see if there is anything in it.

Possible newbie mistake: did you allocate and initialize imagePaths properly?